# How to integrate googletest into an existing VS2015 solution?

Tags: googletest

My first approach was to create an extra static library that compiled `gtest-all.cc`, `gmock-all.cc` and `gmock-main.cc` (to do without `main` in the test project).
The googletest project compiled, but I got this link error in the test project:

`Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl testing::internal::Mutex::AssertHeld(void)" (?AssertHeld@Mutex@internal@testing@@QEAAXXZ)`

What preprocessor or projects settings avoid this link error for x64?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to tweak my googletest project settings to avoid that error.

Since googletest has complicated macros to satisfy all supported platforms,
that knowledge should be internal to googletest itself.
So the solution is not to create your own project for e.g. a static library.

I found two solutions:

- One can put `gtest-all.cc` and `gmock-all.cc` into the test project.
- In `googletest/readme.md` one finds that one can *generate* VS2015 solutions.
  The following command generates the project `gmock_main` that creates a `.lib` that does not have the above link error.

  `cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -Dgtest_build_samples=ON <path to>googletest\googlemock`